# Compile time type generator for integer id based callback map

Tags: c++, boost

The solution must be compilable on gcc 4.2 & vs2012sp1.

I need to implement a callback system. The various callbacks must be available as type inside the CallbackMap so that people can work with types instead of ids. The ID must be a compile time constant because it is used in various compile time checks. The callbacks must be able to be "looked up" by their ID, the lookup happens at runtime.

Additional constraint:
I must be able to control the ID range. First ID could be 20 for instance. And the id_type may not be size_t but a 16/32/64bit integral.

The problem: As this CallbackMap is growing, people who change it get the ID counting wrong more often than right. I'd like the compiler to count for me and as nice to have register the callback as well somehow.

An example of the current solution:

```
#include <boost/signals2/signal.hpp>
#include <map>

typedef size_t id_type;
typedef boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig_type;

#define REGISTER_CALLBACK(NAME) cb_map_[NAME.ID] = &NAME;

struct CallbackBase
{
  sig_type sig;
};

template <id_type N>
struct Callback : CallbackBase
{
  static const size_t ID = N;
};

struct CallbackMap
{
  Callback<1> cb1;
  Callback<2> cb2;
  Callback<3> cb3;

  CallbackMap()
  {
    REGISTER_CALLBACK(cb1);
    REGISTER_CALLBACK(cb2);
    REGISTER_CALLBACK(cb3);
  }

  CallbackBase& GetCallback(id_type id)
  { // I know, no checks here..
    return *cb_map_.find(id)->second;
  }

private:
  std::map<id_type, CallbackBase*> cb_map_;
};

int main()
{
  CallbackMap cb;

  // Register handlers for callbacks
  // cb.cb1.sig.connect(...)

  int incomingRuntimeId = 2;
  cb.GetCallback(incomingRuntimeId).sig();

  return 0;
}
```

I'd like something like this (better even without the REGISTER_CALLBACK):

```
struct CallbackMap
{
  DECLARE_CALLBACK(cb1);
  DECLARE_CALLBACK(cb2);
  DECLARE_CALLBACK(cb3);

  CallbackMap()
  {
    REGISTER_CALLBACK(cb1);
    REGISTER_CALLBACK(cb2);
    REGISTER_CALLBACK(cb3);
  }
  ...
};
```

Even a complete rework of my design but with similiar usage would be nice as well as every suggestion for improvement.
Thanks

Comment: You could do what `std::type_index` does and use the address of the `typeid` of your type as a unique identifier.

Comment: I didn't know `std::type_index` and will have a look, but I should have stated it more clearly that I need this to be C++03 compliant (gcc 4.2)

Comment: That's why I didn't say "use `type_index`", but "do what `type_index` does". You can always *learn* from others, even if you can't *be* them.